# [jQuery]Data array binding

Tags: jquery, arrays, data-binding

I have an issue with array binding included into an a data attribute.

The scenario:

```
<div class="rooms" data="room_14 room_10 room_9 room_5 room_4 room_12"></div>
```

I push the data into an array like this:

```
var dataTags = $(".rooms").data("tags");
var splitTags = dataTags.split(" ");

var arrayRooms = {
  "privilege": [],
  "standard": []
};

for ( i = 0; i < Roomslength; i++ ) {
   arrayRooms.privilege.push(splitTags[i]);
}
```

After that I have to append value on the right html class name (eg. class="room_11")

```
arrRooms.privilege.forEach(function(index,value){
  $('.'+index).html('Room '+parseInt(value + 1));
});
```

I need to associate the lowest value room with value = 0, in this example the room_4 and have this situation:

```
index: room_4 - value: 0 
index: room_5 - value: 1
index: room_9 - value: 2
index: room_10 - value: 3
index: room_12 - value: 4
index: room_14 - value: 5
```

How I can do?

Thanks